# Mysql stored procedure error 1064

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm working on some code, and got stuck on this stored procedure problem... Have spent too long now looking at it, so please if someone can tell me where I am a noob with this.

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@ownerid varchar(50);
>       declare @active tinyint;
>       declare @subuser tinyint;
>       set ' at line 4

on this code:

```
    DELIMITER //

USE `test`//

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getAccount`//

CREATE DEFINER=`peter`@`%` PROCEDURE `getAccount`( IN cid VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    DECLARE cardid VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @ownerid VARCHAR(50);
    DECLARE @active TINYINT;
    DECLARE @subuser TINYINT;
    SET cardid = MD5( cid + SHA1(cid + 'a salt value'));

    SELECT @active = active, @ownerid = ownerid, @subuser = subuser FROM cards_tbl WHERE cardhash = cardid;

    IF @active = 1 THEN
        IF @subuser = 1 THEN
            SELECT subuser_m2s_tbl.name,subuser_m2s_tbl.image, user_saldo.saldo AS credits FROM subuser_m2s_tbl 
            JOIN user_saldo ON subuser_m2s_tbl.subhash = user_saldo.userhash 
            WHERE subuser_m2s_tbl.subhash = @ownerid;
        ELSE
            SELECT user_m2s_tbl.name,user_m2s_tbl.image, user_saldo.saldo AS credits FROM user_m2s_tbl 
            JOIN user_saldo ON user_m2s_tbl.userhash = user_saldo.userhash 
            WHERE user_m2s_tbl.userhash = @ownerid; 
        END IF;
    END IF; 
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Am new to the stored procedures, so it is properly something very simple.....
Thanks in advance

Comment: try removing the @ in front of the variables..

Comment: That actually got the procedure to run(thanks so far), but now I get the 3 variables as the result and nothing from one of the next 2 select statements, which was what I was expecting to get?!? Any help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ':=' instead of '=' when you want to pass value into variable in SELECT statement, otherwise MySQL just will compare to operands.

```
SELECT
  active_var := active, ownerid_var := ownerid, subuser_var := subuser
FROM
  cards_tbl
WHERE
  cardhash = cardid;
```

Also you can use SELECT INTO statement, e.g. -

```
SELECT
  active, ownerid, subuser
INTO
  active_var, ownerid_var, subuser_var
FROM
  cards_tbl
WHERE
  cardhash = cardid;
```

[SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Comment: So far thanks for all your help and suggestions, I only have one problem left, which is my md5/sha1 line doesn't work, can someone help me with this? Apparently mysql doesn't understand it?

Comment: Not sure why, but this line doesn't return the right answer:
SET cardid = MD5( cid + SHA1(cid + 'a salt value'));

Comment: Formulate a question, add more information about the problem. Maybe, write new question.

Answer (score 0):

Is it maybe the missing @

```
DECLARE cardid VARCHAR(50);

...

DECLARE @cardid VARCHAR(50);
```